# Comparar una lista contra dos listas una con valores mayores y otra con valores menores e imprimir que no rebasen el limite

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola espero me puedan ayudar.

Tengo estas listas que previamente obtuve:
Si se podrán dar cuenta tienen un +- 30%

```
superior = [130000.0, 130000.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0]
despues = [10, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100000, 10]
inferior = [70000.0, 70000.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0]
```

La idea es comparar la lista "despues" en contra de la superior y de la inferior y revisar si excede los valores de estas listas.

Este es el codigo que utilizo pero al parecer recorre el primer elemento de de la primera lista con los elementos de la segunda y este a su vez con la tercera haciendo imposible un resultado al menos para mì.

```
for i in range(len(superior)):
    for j in range(len(despues)):
        for k in range(len(inferior)):
            if inferior[i] >= despues[j] and despues[j] <= superior[k]:
                print(f"El valor de {despues[j]} esta dentro de los limites")
            else:
                print(f"El valor de {despues[j]} esta fuera de rango")
```

Espero me puedan ayudar!

Saludos!

Comment: `[despues[i] for i in range(len(despues)) if inferior[i] <= despues[i] <= superior[i]]` produce los valores pedidos.

Comment: Tu problema es que recorres las tres listas en tres bucles **anidados**, esto hace que por cada elemento de la lista 1, se iteren todas las veces por la lista 2, y a su vez por cada uno de éstos, se itera todas las veces por la lista 3. Así, si las tres listas tuvieran 100 elementos cada una estarías iterando 100*100*100 = un millón de veces. En realidad necesitas iterar solo 100 veces y en cada iteración sacar un elemento de cada lista. Esto puedes hacerlo con el bucle del comentario de CandiMoe o con el zip de la respuesta de HeytalePazguato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Podrías crear un [`zip`](https://ellibrodepython.com/zip-python) de las 3 listas para comparar conjuntos de valores. Con zip puedes crear una tupla de valores creado con los mismos índices de las 3 listas, es decir, se creará una tupla con `(inferior[0], despues[0], superior[0])`, luego con el índice `1`, `2` y así sucesivamente.

Por cierto, cuando comparas un valor entre límite inferior y superior puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma para evitar usar `and`:

```
limiteInferior <= valor <= limiteSuperior
```

Ejemplo:

```
superior = [130000.0, 130000.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0]
despues = [10, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100000, 10]
inferior = [70000.0, 70000.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0]

for limInf, valor, limSup in zip(inferior, despues, superior):
    if limInf <= valor <= limSup:
        print(f"El valor de {valor} esta dentro de los limites")
    else:
        print(f"El valor de {valor} esta fuera de rango")
```

Esto imprime:

```
El valor de 10 esta fuera de rango
El valor de 20 esta fuera de rango
El valor de 10 esta dentro de los limites
El valor de 10 esta dentro de los limites
El valor de 10 esta dentro de los limites
El valor de 10 esta dentro de los limites
El valor de 10 esta dentro de los limites
El valor de 10 esta dentro de los limites
El valor de 10 esta dentro de los limites
El valor de 10 esta dentro de los limites
El valor de 10 esta dentro de los limites
El valor de 10 esta dentro de los limites
El valor de 10 esta dentro de los limites
El valor de 10 esta dentro de los limites
El valor de 10 esta dentro de los limites
El valor de 10 esta dentro de los limites
El valor de 10 esta dentro de los limites
El valor de 10 esta dentro de los limites
El valor de 100000 esta fuera de rango
El valor de 10 esta dentro de los limites
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!  a todos por el apoyo!